# Regex.IsMatch returning True which is not correct

Tags: c#, regex

I have an extension method like this;

```
public static bool IsBoolean(this string value)
{
    string lower = value.ToLower(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    return new Regex("[true]|[false]|[0]|[1]", RegexOptions.Compiled).IsMatch(lower);
}
```

But this regex pattern fails when I give "fals" or "tru" as value. Such as;

```
[Theory(DisplayName = "IsBoolean")]
[InlineData("FALS")]
[InlineData("Fals")]
[InlineData("TRU")]
[InlineData("Tru")]
public void IsNotBoolean(string value)
{
    bool result = value.IsBoolean();
    Assert.False(result);
}
```

All these tests has been failed. Because result is true.
How is this possible? Is this regex pattern wrong ?

Comment: I think you want `^(true|false|[01])$`, possibly with `RegexOptions.IgnoreCase` option to ignore case. maccettura's advice below should work best though.

Comment: `[true]` matches any of the letters in the set. so `t` will be matched by `[true]`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reference - What does this regex mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22937618/reference-what-does-this-regex-mean)

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but please read up on what `RegexOptions.Compiled` is for, because this is definitely the wrong way to use it.

Comment: Thank you very much for comments. Yes, @WiktorStribiżew that's work, now I can check what is ^ and $ for. And bool.TryParse is better I know. Last think "hvd" I Thanks for point it out. Actually I refactored code to ask. Source code is different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want check if the string is any one of the following, ignoring case,

```
true
false
1
0
```

Then you just separate those strings with `|` and use that as the regex, and use the `IgnoreCase` option:

```
public static bool IsBoolean(this string value) {
    // note the ^ and $. They assert the start and end of the string.
    return new Regex("^(?:true|false|0|1)$", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase).IsMatch(value);
}
```

`[]` denotes a character class, so it will match any one character inside it. `[abc]` matches *either* `a`, `b` or `c`. Note the difference.

Comment: It was wrong even in the question, but `XtrueY` gives `true` :-) `^(true|false|0|1)$` would probably be better

Comment: @xanatos Thanks for reminding me! I had been working with Java where I don't need those...